# merging intervals and timestamps dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I have a table which contains intervals

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [0, 101, 666], 'Stop': [100, 200, 1000]})
```

I have another table which contains timestamps and values

```
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': [102, 145, 113], 'ValueA': [1, 2, 21],
'ValueB': [1, 2, 21]})
```

I need to create a dataframe same size as `dfa`, with added a columns which contains the result of some aggregation of `ValueA`/`ValueB`, for all the rows in `dfb` with a `Timestamp` contained between `Start` and `Stop`.

So here if define my aggregation as

```
{'ValueA':[np.nanmean,np.nanmin],
'ValueB':[np.nanmax]}
```

my desired output would be:

```
ValueA   ValueA    ValueB
nanmean  nanmin    nanmax    Start      Stop

nan      nan       nan        0          100
8        1         21         101        200
nan      nan       nan        666        1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with cross join with helper columns created by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
d = {'ValueA':[np.nanmean,np.nanmin],
     'ValueB':[np.nanmax]}

df = dfa.assign(A=1).merge(dfb.assign(A=1), on='A', how='outer')
```

Then filter by `Start` and `Stop` and aggregate by dictionary:

```
df = (df[(df.Timestamp >= df.Start) & (df.Timestamp <= df.Stop)]
         .groupby(['Start','Stop']).agg(d))
```

Flatten MultiIndex by `map` with `join`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
            ValueA_nanmean  ValueA_nanmin  ValueB_nanmax
Start Stop                                              
101   200                8              1             21
```

And last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = dfa.join(df, on=['Start','Stop'])
print (df)
   Start  Stop  ValueA_nanmean  ValueA_nanmin  ValueB_nanmax
0      0   100             NaN            NaN            NaN
1    101   200             8.0            1.0           21.0
2    666  1000             NaN            NaN            NaN
```

EDIT:

Solution with [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
d = {'ValueA':[np.nanmean,np.nanmin],
     'ValueB':[np.nanmax]}

#if not default index create it
dfa = dfa.reset_index(drop=True)
print (dfa)
   Start  Stop
0      0   100
1    101   200
2    666  1000

#add to bins first value of Start
bins = np.insert(dfa['Stop'].values, 0, dfa.loc[0, 'Start'])
print (bins)
[   0  100  200 1000]

#binning
dfb['id'] = pd.cut(dfb['Timestamp'], bins=bins, labels = dfa.index)
print (dfb)
   Timestamp  ValueA  ValueB id
0        102       1       1  1
1        145       2       2  1
2        113      21      21  1

#aggregate and flatten
df = dfb.groupby('id').agg(d)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

#add to dfa
df = pd.concat([dfa, df], axis=1)
print (df)
   Start  Stop  ValueA_nanmean  ValueA_nanmin  ValueB_nanmax
0      0   100             NaN            NaN            NaN
1    101   200             8.0            1.0           21.0
2    666  1000             NaN            NaN            NaN
```

Comment: while this solves the question, and I will anyway approve the answer: I am having performance issues since the outer join produces millions of rows. any hint to improve performance?

Comment: @00__00__00 - added solution with cut.